# Как релизовать обобщённый метод для определённого типа данных?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

На С++ я задавала реализацию функции для определённого типа данных и общую для всех остальных. Попытка сделать так же на C# выдаёт мне ошибку компиляции `Type 'SomeType' already defines a member called 'SomeGenericMethod' with the same parameter types`. Неужели нельзя задать тип возвращаемого значения для метода, используя обобщения? Ответы в этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959957/c-specialized-template-method-error-type-already-defines-a-member-cal не удовлетворили меня. Как по мне, они костыльные.

```
private T SomeGenericMethod<T>()
{
    // реализация для большинства типов
} 

private T SomeGenericMethod<T>() where T: myDataType
{
    // реализация в случае если T - myDataType
}
```

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то, что метод с аналогичной сигнатурой уже используется. Методы с одинаковой сигнатурой создавать нельзя. Только я понять не могу: если Вы ограничиваете использование строго определённым типом, то к чему тогда обобщённый метод?

Comment: @XelaNimed для создания нескольких реализаций одного метода.

Comment: @XelaNimed если создание ограничения на принимаемый методом тип не является изменением его сигнатуры, то как реализовать в данном случае мою идею? Изменением названия метода или списка аргументов? Тогда пропадёт полиморфизм.

Comment: Может быть интерфейс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно спецификации языка (пункт 3.6), в сигнатуру не входят ни тип возвращаемого значения, ни тип-параметр обобщенного метода, ни какие-либо ограничения на тип-параметр.

Таким образом, с точки зрения компилятора, ваши методы неразличимы, т.к. имеют одинаковые имена и наборы входных параметров. В вашем примере входных параметров нет, следовательно будут учитываться только имена. **Обобщенные типы C# похожи, но не эквивалентны шаблонам C++.**

Вам необходимо

- либо иметь два метода с различными сигнатурами (в
  приведенном примере - различными именами), если они являются членами
  одного класса/структуры,
- либо разнести их в разные классы/структуры с общим предком или
  интерфейсом,
- либо определить два интерфейса с данной сигнатурой метода и
  использовать явную реализацию интерфейсов в классе/структуре,
- либо воспользоваться одним из решений по приведенной вами ссылке.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
T SomeGenericMethod<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(myDataType))
    {
        myDataType retval = // реализация в случае если T - myDataType
        return (dynamic)retval;
    }
    else
    {
        // реализация для большинства типов
    }
}
```

Только я не представляю, что вы впихнете вместо "реализация для большинства типов", так чтобы это скомпилировалось. Разве что `default(T)`. Собственно, решения кажутся "костыльными", потому что вы пытаетесь применить обобщенные методы не по назначению: они предназначены для реализации тех алгоритмов, которые не привязаны к конкретному типу данных. Если для каждого типа реализация своя, вам просто нужно несколько перегруженных методов.